# Combining pandas dataframes, different number of lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Two data frames of different lengths:**

```
df1:                               df2:
Column1  Column2  Column3          Column1  Column2
Url      Name      Description     Type 1   Duration 1
                                   Type 2   Duration 2
                                   Type 3   Duration 3
                                   Type 4   Duration 4
```

**How to get such a table?**

```
Column1  Column2  Column3          Column4  Column5

Url1      Name1     Description1   Type *   Duration 1
                                   Type 2   Duration 2
                                   Type 3   Duration 3
                                   Type 4   Duration 4
```

I want to write data to Excel table.
[An example of the required table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm1WO.png)

**Tried:**

```
df1.merge (df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
df2.join (df2)
```

**As a result, only one line from df2 is written**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Solution - pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)